# How to put filename with whitespace in awk

Tags: awk

In a bash file `test.sh`, I put

```
#!/bin/bash

dirpath="/home/dir"
myfile="$dirpath/file with white space"  
awk '{print "firstcolumn"$1":"$4,$2}' ${myfile}.bim >file2
```

When I run the script `sh test.sh`, I receive an error saying
`awk: fatal: cannot open file '/home/dir/file' for reading (No such file or directory)`. How do I make awk to deal with file with whitespaces?
I tried file\ with\ white\ space as well but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same as in other contexts, you quote it:

```bsh
awk '{print "firstcolumn"$1":"$4,$2}' "${myfile}.bim" >file2
```

This will also prevent the case where you have filenames with glob characters `myfile="$dirpath/*"`